# How i can get variables and values in a monoscript object in Unity3d C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need get all variables on a monoscript Object on Unity 3D.
How i can do this?
I have a monoscript on the inspector, and i can access him (the monoscript object) but i can't get the variables with his methods (monoscript methods).
Is there any way I can get all monoscript variables? I'm developing an Asset save load and therefore need to take the variables and their current values at the time I access the monoscritp.

I hope you can help me, thank you.
Sorry if posted little information, any questions just ask. Thank you.

Comment: Are you talking about a MonoBehaviour script? And do you mean you are trying to serialise such a script?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get instance of MonoBehaviour. There is many way to do this(Declare public variable and drag & drop gameobject on editor, or GameObject.Find to get gameobject and using GetComponent method)

And then you can access variables or methods those are public member.